# How can I fix this error in my startup script?

Tags: python, bots

I am having this trouble with my script because I'm trying to login all instances of my bot(they're the same code base, A group chat helper for another platform), I have one script which calls 'main.py' as a sub-process to login all the bots.

top of my main.py:

```
username = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]


def main():
    # set up logging
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(KikClient.log_format()))
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

the contents of my start.py:

```
accounts = []

with open("accts.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        accounts.append(line.split(":"))
    pList = []
    for acc in accounts:
        p = subprocess.Popen(
            ['python', 'main.py', acc[0], acc[1]])  # i also used device_id and android_id overrides, use if you want
        pList.append(p)
        time.sleep(2)  # to be safe
```

this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    username = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Maybe try printing out `sys.argv` in main.py to get a hint of what it's seeing

Comment: I will try this rn

Comment: the correct data is being passed into the sys.argv's

Comment: so the output looked something like `['main.py', '<user>', '<pass>']`? That really isn't possible... sys.argv must not contain more than a single element for the error you're seeing to be happening

Comment: just the username and psw

Comment: username psw 

in that format

Comment: Try this. username = sys.argv[0]

Comment: @toyotaSupra, to have script file name as a username?

Comment: @BaconBacon, please strip your code to a minimal reproducible example, so that everybody could test that with just 2 files.

Comment: Use `print(sys.argv)` and copy the exact results here. if username and password are real values, you can just replace them with `username` and `password` but keep all other characters unchanged

Comment: would you mind putting up an answer so i can have a bit of an example?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are not providing a third argument to the program when executing it from the command line.

Example:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

Running it like this:

```
python test.py
```

Gives off the same error(`list index out of range`).
You need to run it like this by providing a third argument when executing it:

```
python test.py something
```

Results in the program printing the third argument, `something`.
Hope this will help!

Comment: The error message is coming from main.py, which is called by subprocess with the arguments we see in the code (`acc[0]` and `acc[1]`)

Comment: @drootang Right, then he should check wether the first and second values in the accounts list aren't blank.

Comment: They are not blank

Comment: Well the first and second values in the account list are for sure blank. If your text file isn't blank maybe you need to check whether your script reads and parses the content of the file correctly.